# Why was a 'not an answer' flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I was reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5454683) first post and flagged it as 'not an answer' as it did not appear to answer the original question.

The flag appear as 'disputed' in my 'flagged posts' summary " not an answer – DavidPostill 13 hours ago   **disputed**"

Looking again at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788202/how-do-i-check-if-session-start-has-been-entered/25108782#25108782) I now see the following comment from a high-rep user (which was not there during the review):

"**This does not provide an answer to the question**. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post."

As his comments agrees with my flag why was my flag labelled **disputed** instead of **helpful** (which is what I would expect)?

Comment: Related: the whole Related section in the right sidebar. To be fair, some of us do not really know anymore what actually constitutes "not an answer"... and the consensus about that seems to be changing (again).

Comment: In a nutshell: Because it looks like an answer. It may be answering something entirely different to what was asked, but it looks like an answer to *something*. As Frédéric pointed out, most of the Related posts are relevant to this, but specifically I'd suggest reading [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/).

Comment: It's an answer, but it is wrong. That's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Not An Answer flag was sent into the [Low Quality Review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5454727).  The result of the review was *Looks OK × 3, Delete × 1* which resulted in a disputed flag - this means that users with review privileges disagreed with your flag.

The comment was placed on the answer but the user who voted to delete the answer but the overall result of the review was people disagree with your initial flag.

Comment: Wouldn't it help if SO revealed this data like they do for suggested edits? Seems like it would cut down on the questions or reasoning.